# MongoDb index date or timestamp perfomance

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to optimize a collection that is basically a 2 field collection:

| ID | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 10000000000 |
| 11 | 10000000000 |
| 12 | 10000020000 |

The timestamp column is exactly the title. A timestamp.
I need two index for both the fields. Now my questions are:

Does it makes difference if I create an index for the field *timestamp* as a timestamp or a Date type?

Does it changes at a performance level?

Answer (score 1):

If your timestamps are always 32-bit integers, use a 32-bit integer field.

Otherwise BSON timestamp type isn't appropriate and you need to use the BSON date type.